# How to get tags outside of loop for specific page I'm on?

Tags: tags

Outside the loop, if I use the following code in my child theme...

```
  $mtags = get_tags(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'custom_tag',
        'orderby' => 'name'
      ));
```

It prints out all my tags.  But how can I only get tags relating to the page I am viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the ID of the page/post/content you're viewing. Then, you can call `get_the_terms()` and pass it that ID so it knows you want the tags for that specific piece of content.

```
<?php
$mtags = get_the_terms( get_queried_object_id(), 'custom_tag' );
?>
```

There isn't an `orderby` parameter, so you may need to sort the array afterward if you want them in a specific order.

Comment: If they're outside the loop `get_queried_object_id()` would be more reliable for getting the current post ID.

Comment: Edited above - thanks, that's a nice improvement.